"Come home to"—Usage
I "came home to" an unhappy state of affairs.
—From Cambridge dictionary
What's the phrase express in this context, after my research I only found the phrase refers to"fully understand something". I need some suggestions with this

It could be literal.  I arrived back home to find a bad situation.  In the person's absence, things took a bad turn.

@TimR why there is "to" after it, is it a part of "come home" or any other grammatical role?

to introduces the situation encountered upon arrival: "We came home to a mess. Our teenage son had thrown a party while we were away."  Or "I came home to my loving family."  or "We arrived to an empty train platform. The train had left a few  minutes early."

The metaphorical sense of 'fully understanding' something is It came home to me that...

@KateBunting  It is being used literally or metaphorically?

The metaphorical meaning "I came to realize, I came to understand" requires  "It came home to me that .... ".

And there is the unrelated usage in the expression the chickens come home to roost, which means that the undesirable consequences of an action or decision arise (happen). But in the parse of this expression we don’t have come home to and the noun roost; rather, we have come home, [in order] to, and the verb roost.

Sam, both Tim and I have told you that the metaphorical sense is expressed differently. There is no context to the dictionary example, but presumably it is literal (as Tim explains in his original comment).

@KateBunting I came home amidst unhappy state of affairs.Is it ok?

@PaulTanenbaum  I came home amidst unhappy state of affairs.Is it ok?

@TimR  I came home amidst unhappy state of affairs.Is it ok?

If you mean that you found an unhappy state of affairs when you reached home - no, it isn't idiomatic. If you mean that you were travelling during a difficult situation, it might just be OK, provided that you include the indefinite article.

"came home to {a mess}" can be paraphrased a "When I arrived home, I was greeted by a mess" or "I found a mess awaiting me when I returned home".  amidst does not have this sense of being greeted by something.  With amidst, you are already in the mess while you are on your way home.   If your country declares war while you are away from home, you can come home amidst a sad state of affairs.

The phrase "came home to" can be used in two ways:
Literally
Here "came come to" means "when I arrived home I found..."

I came home to an unhappy state of affairs. The pipes had burst and my wife was trying to calm my young son. She said "At last! You're back! Now fix the pipes or call a plumber."

Figuratively
This is the sense where it means :"come to fully understand something".

After I had called the plumber, it came home to me that my wife was very stressed from having to look after a young child and do house maintenance at the same time. I wish I had realized that sooner.

When used figuratively we almost always say "it came home to me" and not "I came home to". When someone says "I came home to..." it is virtually always the literal usage.

I came home amidst unhappy state of affairs.Is it ok?

Ask another question, and say why you think it might not be OK.

The idiom
come home to means

to become very clear and obvious to (someone) in usually a forceful or unpleasant way
The truth about her marriage came home to her when he left her.

M+W explains come home to.
The original post can't use this idiom; its
came home has to
take the literal meaning.
I returned home ...
To use that idiom, we
could say
Edit

It came home to me that this was an unhappy state of affairs.


I came home amidst unhappy state of affairs.Is it ok?

Thanks, @Kate Bunting.  Agreed and incorporated.
